Windows 10 High RAM usage with no process used until a BSOD
Similar to the issue here, I'm facing a very high RAM usage in Windows 10 after a recent update (it's been over 30 days so I can't rollback).
My memory constantly sits at 80%



Some people have said that this is normal behavior since the OS would clear RAM when you need it, however that's not the case with me as I run into app crashes and once a week I run into a BSOD. When I boot into safe mode and leave the PC running overnight everything is fine. I tried using Poolmon and I can see the tag EtwB as the one using the most amount of RAM, which is roughly 100MB:

Any advice on what I can do next to identify the problem?
Edit: Added more Memory Profiles to task manager image

Edit 2: Added CPU Tab

Edit 3: RAMMap


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I reinstalled Realtek Audio Driver and the issue remained, so then I reinstalled
Steam, Epic Games, and Google Chrome. Then I uninstalled SteelSeries GG and Logitech Hub (they were both disabled and unused). Now the issue is gone. So this was definitely a memory leak.
